# spring-boot auto-configuration ignores application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

placed in the classpath root (src/main/resources).

a application.properties file in the same place is properly used.

this is the code:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestResource {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> test() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("text", "test text");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestResource.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to add dependency on snakeyaml. example maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this isn't relevant since version 1.0.0 (yaml dependencies are provided by spring-boot)